# Proving that if $x$ is irrational, then $\frac1x$ is irrational

Tags: solution-verification

I was given the question:

> Prove that if $x$ is irrational, then $\frac1x$ is irrational

I did this through contraposition, namely:

if $\frac1x$ is rational, it can be written in the form $\frac ab$ where b is nonzero.

Thus,  $\frac1x = \frac ab$ which gives $ x = \frac ba$, so $x$ is also rational, hereby indirectly proving that the original statement is true.

I couldn't find this proven in the way I did when looking for it on the internet, so where did I go wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that it is wrong?

Comment: Things can be proven in more than one way. In a couple course I took I found a proof the professor hadn't seen before. Being new to the subject doesn't mean you can't find a new way forward.

Comment: I thought I was wrong because the next question in the book was asking for basically the same answer if it was right.

Comment: It may be worth taking a brief moment to explain why $a\neq 0$.

Comment: $ a$ ≠ 0 because $\frac1x$ = $\frac ab$ is equal to $x$= $\frac 1\frac ab$ where $\frac ab$ is nonzero, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct,
and merits a bit more precision: You should not ignore zero as mentioned in a comment, e.g. by writing
If $\frac1x$ is a nonzero rational, it can be written in the form $\frac ab$ where both $a,b$ are nonzero.

Multiplicative inversion
$\iota:\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}\to\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}, x\mapsto\tfrac1x$ is invertible, being its own inverse: $\iota^{-1}=\iota\,$.
It maps $\,\mathbb Q\backslash\{0\}\,$ to itself, whence it maps the irrationals
$\,\mathbb R\backslash\mathbb Q\,$ to itself as well.

Comment: I am unfortunately not nearly far enough in my studies to transcribe that second paragraph